# Error in iOS - Crashes at [[WL sharedInstance] showSplashScreen];

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm getting the following error when I run the iOS app from MobileFirst version 6.3

```
2015-11-06 11:42:37.778 AvnetR20ZurbMobileApp[169:60b] [DEBUG] [WL_SPLASH] -[WLSplashView updateImage] in WLSplashView.m:194 :: Splash screen image is Default

2015-11-06 11:42:37.783 AvnetR20ZurbMobileApp[169:60b] -[__NSDictionaryI WLJSONRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1700f5900

2015-11-06 11:42:37.785 AvnetR20ZurbMobileApp[169:60b] *** <b> **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI WLJSONRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1700f5900'** </b>

*** First throw call stack:(0x186612f50 0x192b1c1fc 0x186617c04 0x186615930 0x1865355dc 0x10018aedc 0x1930f3fd4 0x1930f9c84 0x10018aa2c 0x10018cd84 0x10010db5c 0x10010d2f4 0x10010cbc4 0x1001abb38 0x1895dc488 0x1895dc3f4 0x189693a74 0x1896d435c 0x1896d2c3c 0x1896d1a9c 0x10015bb34 0x1000f231c 0x10005df44 0x18965055c 0x18964ff08 0x1896499ec 0x1895dd8cc 0x1895dcad0 0x189649044 0x18c1fb504 0x18c1fb030 0x1865d2e90 0x1865d2df0 0x1865d1014 0x186511c20 0x1896481c8 0x189642fdc 0x10005dc90 0x19310faa0)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I'm unable to trace this out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Download the latest iFix from IBM Fix Central and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your question whether you are referring to a hybrid or native question, nor what is your full version and build number.

From a quick test of both in 6.3, this is working so I suggest two things:

1. Test with the latest iFix
2. If still failing afterwards, provide an application that can be debugged to see why it is failing